# "Make a score of"

Tags: meaning, sports

Besides for telling the score on a test (as in "He made a score of 88 out of 100 on the test"), can the phrase "to make a score of" be used to describe the score in a soccer/association football match? For example:

> England made a score of two goals to zero. [If the final score is 2-0.]

Comment: It's not exactly standard usage to speak of *making a score* - except perhaps in some circumstances where it's a somewhat "slangy" equivalent to ***managed to achieve** a score* in contexts where the score was better than would have been expected.

Answer (score 2):

Google results for "made a score of" show, in the first pages of hits, only two situations where the expression is used:

1. in tests / exams (and I believe this is largely a US usage - 'got' or 'achieved' would be more common in the UK
2. in cricket matches, where one team will 'bat' and post a score in an 'innings', whilst the other team 'fields': *England scored / made a score of 525 for 7 in their first innings*.

Comment: No native US speaker I know of says *made a score of*- that seems like something a foreign speaker would say.  In the US *got* is probably most common, also *gave me* as in *he only gave me an 89, what a jerk*.  *Received* might also be used a little more formally.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of "making" a score is common in the sport of cricket but (perversely) the word *score* is usually omitted. So a match description might read "Warner made a quick-fire 80 to get the team off to a great start". The alternative and slightly more formal statement would be "Warner scored 80 quickly."

Note that it is not usual to use "made" (or "scored") when referring to the overall result of the match (as in your example) when the numbers of goals or runs made by both teams are given.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider more precise phraseology within the context of very formal writing, but for anything else, it's perfectly functional usage. That is to say, any native or fluent speaker of English will perfectly understand your intent in a wide variety of contexts.

"England *scored* three goals" is certainly the most common usage in the context of sports (at least here in the U.S.), but nobody's going to be confused by "England made three goals", nor will "England made a score of three" seem noticeably awkward.

However, for conversational purposes it *does* seem like nothing more than the addition of three unnecessary syllables over the monosyllabic "scored".

Comment: Is *phraseology* the learnèd study of phrases?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat counterintuitively, "phraseology" actually refers to word choice, syntax formation, etc. In this case, ignore wikipedia, and check out [a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phraseology).